# Cannot attach database file when setup application on other computer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I have put my database file (.mdf) in bin\debug folder and use this app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="XtopazConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\XTOPAZ.mdf;Initial Catalog=XTOPAZ;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

and attach database function:

```
public static void openConnect()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ.mdf"))
        {
            if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ_log.ldf")) //delete current ldf file if it existed
            {
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ_log.ldf");
            }
            string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XtopazConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            //Set full permisstion access for database file
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ.mdf");
            DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
            dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
            dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
            dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

            con.ConnectionString = s;
            con.Open();
        }
        else
        {
            Exception ex;
            ex = new Exception("Database file not found");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occured when trying to connect to database\r\nDetail: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I use InstallShield in Visual Studio 2012 to create setup.exe and install it in other computer (in my C# project, there is no error), I see this error:
[image: Error when attaching database]

How can I solve this problem? I have googled it but I can't find the solution.

Comment: You're using `Integrated Security=True` in the connectionstring. I would guess that you are able to log in to the database using your windows credentials, but the user experiencing the error is not able to log in using their windows credentials.

Comment: @Smudge202 , should I change `Integrated Security=False` ?

Answer (score 0):

This `AttachDbFileName=` approach works **only** with SQL Server **Express** - so you must ensure that a local SQL Server Express instance is present and running.

The default instance name for that is `.\SQLEXPRESS` - so I would suggest you try this connection string:

```
<add name="XtopazConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\XTOPAZ.mdf;Initial Catalog=XTOPAZ;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I tried this connection string but this error is still occur